# How do mysql work with django, when you upload your project to a hosting service?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am having trouble understanding how something works with mysql and django. Im trying to create a project and connect it to mysql. By the way, im completely new to DJANGO and MYSQL.

I know you have to get xampp to get into the localhost/phpmyadmin...

I know you have to change the database in your django project settings.

i know you have to install mysqlclient with pip..
i have did all of that and dont get me wrong, it works perfect.

i understand how it connects to localhost/phpmyadmin.. uses the username and password i passed in to get the data --- ****i think???***

BUT my question is this.. when i put my project on a hosting service, like pythonanywhere......how would my django project know how to get the mysql at my localhost?????? Im confused at this point and i havent been able to publish my website. The code works perfectly in localhost of course, but what happens when i publish it on a hosting service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, once your site is published, it will use some sort of production database (compared to your local development database on `localhost`).

Your hosting service will have to support MySQL, of course. Fortunately, [PythonAnywhere does](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/UsingMySQL/), and the linked documentation actually has documentation [for Django too](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/UsingMySQL/#mysql-with-django).

If you have built your site in your development database, the easiest way to get it into production is to use `mysqldump` (or PHPMyAdmin) to get a .sql file that contains all of the data in your database, then import it to the production database using whichever tool is available on your host.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I really appreciate that!

Comment: Well, Django is usually used for web apps where you have a development environment that's separate from production, but it depends on your needs. If it's more a site you're building, not an app, you could build directly on PythonAnywhere, I suppose.

Comment: just to make sure i understand correctly. I can make my apps locally, and then once i get ready to put it in productions, I can just setup the database with pythonanywhere, and change the settings in my django settings file to match the pythonanywhere, and everything should be square then?

Comment: When you develop your app, you'd have your settings file point to localhost; on PythonAnywhere (or anywhere else in production), it'd point to the production database. There are many ways to do this though; an easy way is to have a separate settings file.

Comment: Nice! Now I have a better understanding. I think i will just test it out with the sqllite database, and when im putting it into production, ill just hook the database up to the mysql in pythonanywhere.